# (Raphael) Alternative to free_transform.js? (Slow Animation)

Tags: javascript, animation, raphael

I have this web app that creates rows and columns of holes. With each hole there can also be text and a path or 2 associated with it. I have all of these stored in a set.  The user also has the option of moving this set using free_transform.js.  It works great if I have less than 50 holes; less in Firefox for some reason.  But the problem really shows itself when the user decides to create a grid of 100 or more holes.
         The functionality works fine; it's just that the animation is slow to catch up to my mouse movement.  At worst I would say the delay is 2 seconds, but as a client that would be really annoying and of course we don't want to annoy the client. 
        My question is does anyone have experience using Raphael/free_transform in this context? Is there a better solution?  Are the tools I am using insufficient for my goal?